# Connecting two scattered point in lines using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to connect two points using matplotlib.
For example,

```
A=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
B=[8,1]
```

I should connect each (1,2), (3,4), (5,6) three points to (8,1),
I tried to use method like (not this, but similar to this)

```
xs = [x[0] for x in A]
ys = [y[1] for y in A]
plt.plot(xs,ys)
```

but in that way, I should duplicate (8,1) every time between each three points.

Are there any pythonic method to do this?

Comment: Not sure what "pythonic" would refer to, but if you're looking for the most efficient or fastest method to draw many lines, this would be [through a `LineCollection`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54492963/many-plots-in-less-time-python/54544965#54544965).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, what you're trying to do is **connect several points to one point, creating a line with each connection - a many-to-one mapping**.

With that in mind, this is perfectly acceptable:

```
A=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
B=[8,1]

for point in A:
    connection_x = [point[0], B[0]]
    connection_y = [point[1], B[1]]
    plt.plot(connection_x, connection_y)
plt.show()
```

Which results in:[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you have more than one point B that you want to connect to each point A, you can use an itertools approach. Works of course also with only one point per list.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
from itertools import product

A = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
B = [[8,1], [5,7], [3,1]]

for points in product(A, B):
    point1, point2 = zip(*points)
    plt.plot(point1, point2)

plt.show()
```